# Outlook MAPI-Moving Email to Outbox Lands it as Draft

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I write an outlook add-in and I am new to it, so please elaborate.

When I am offline and attempt to send an MailItem, the MailItem is moved to outbox.  However, I noticed (as per screenshot below), that it has "draft" icon and no date.

As a result, when I get online, it will never get sent.

How do I move it to outbox folder but have it land there not as a draft?

I move it lilke this:

```
(myItem as MailItem).Move(myOutboxFolder);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect a message moved to the Outbox folder to become sent? You need to create it in the sent state (it cannot be changed later), and that means you can only create a PostItem, not MailItem.

To send a message, you need to call MailItem.Send. Moving it to the Outbox will not sent it - Outbox is just an eye candy.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I am new to Outlook Add-ins.  So, maybe my explanation about does not make sense.  The bottom line is that I am using MailItem (as I want to send email).  But, if I am offline, that MailItem ends up in Outbox with the draft icon and missing date as per screenshot above.  I expect that once I am back online, the mail item in Outbox to be sent.  However, it is not and I suspect that the reason for that is that it has the draft icon and no date (as per screenshot above).  I have also updated my question above.

Comment: The message does not get sent if you touch it in any way (UI or Object Model) while it is still being transmitted. Make sure the preview pane in the Outbox folder is off and that your code dereferences the message as soon as you call Send.

Comment: I dont touch it in UI but I guess the mode might although I dont see that.  I am currently viewing Inbox folder and not Outbox folder.  So, preview pane has no effect.  So, I guess I have to still figure out how to dereference the message right after call to MailItem.Send